# Inconsistent percent encoding in webapp handlers

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.5

I'm trying to get a handler mapping working with Google App Engine.

The regex is like this:

```
('/api/1/apps/([-0-9a-zA-Z]+)/values/(.+)', ApiValueHandler)
```

When the URL looks like `/api/1/apps/50b96eb0/values/New%20note%2Fhello` the value that gets passed to my handler is `New%20note/hello`. As you can see it's unescaping the slash, but not the space.

Is there a setting I'm missing somewhere, or do I need to do some unescaping myself? If there are some values it will never unescape is there a list of these somewhere?

**Updated:**

Here's a test app that shows this behaviour when run on the dev server on Windows 7 with Python 2.5.

main.py

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, blah):
        self.response.out.write(blah)

app = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/(.*)', MainHandler)], debug=True)
util.run_wsgi_app(app)
```

app.yaml

```
application: engineapp
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: .*
  script: main.py
```

Comment: Show us your code; I've just tried this case in a sample app and the unescaping works without problem.

Comment: @systempuntoout I've added code to the question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not escaped characters are defined by `quote`: letters, digits, `_.-` and the default safe character `/`.

http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote

Just use `unquote` on the matched string.

```
>>> urllib.unquote('/%24/')
'/$/'
```

http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote

Comment: Any reason this was downvoted? If it's not the right answer then can you post a correct one?

Answer (score 1):

Use `urllib.unquote` to unescape the string.

[Example](http://ideone.com/sB9CW)

Comment: Won't that risk double unescaping of values that are already unescaped when they're passed to the handler?